# jquery - HTML5 Audio "paused" property returns true no matter what

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I am trying to make a toggle play function, using an if statement. I use the `.paused` method/property to checking if the `<audio>` element is playing. My problem is that the property returns true even if the audio is playing. Here's my code:

```
var player = $("#player");
var playerE = $("#player")[0];
var playerE = $("#player").get(0);

var isPaused = playerE.paused;

function togglePlay() {
    if (isPaused === false) {
        player.trigger("pause");
    } else {
        player.trigger("play");
    }
}
```

Here's my audio element too:

```
<audio id="player" src="source is added dynamically" controls="controls" preload="none"></audio>
```

If you need to test it out, Here's a snippet:

```js
var player = $("#player");
var playerE = $("#player")[0];
var playerE = $("#player").get(0);
var isPaused = playerE.paused;

function togglePlay() {
    if (isPaused === false) {
        player.trigger("pause");
    } else {
        player.trigger("play");
    }
}

/** Added for testing **/

function check() {
  alert(isPaused);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="player" src="http://98678871.ngrok.io/music/test.mp3" controls="controls" preload="none"></audio>
<button onclick="check()">Check isPlaying</button>
```

As you can see, it returns true even if the audio IS playing. What is going on here? Is this a bug?

Comment: You never change isPaused in your togglePlay function.

Comment: No why would I need to do that? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_paused.asp

Comment: isPaused is a value, not a reference. If you want your check function to work, simply alert playerE.paused instead.

Comment: I stored it in a variable in order to not repeat the same code over and over each time I need the .paused bolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between a reference, and a value.

If you say `var isPaused = playerE.paused;` it's the same as saying `var isPaused = true;`. isPaused isn't going to change when playerE.paused changes.

Thus, when you check for the paused state, you must use playerE.paused.

```js
var player = $("#player");
var playerE = $("#player")[0];
var playerE = $("#player").get(0);
var isPaused = playerE.paused;

function togglePlay() {
    if (isPaused === false) {
        player.trigger("pause");
    } else {
        player.trigger("play");
    }
}

/** Added for testing **/

function check() {
  alert(playerE.paused);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="player" src="http://98678871.ngrok.io/music/test.mp3" controls="controls" preload="none"></audio>
<button onclick="check()">Check isPlaying</button>
```

You can always just listen to when the video/audio pauses/plays and update your variable based on that.

```js
var player = $("#player");
var playerE = $("#player")[0];
var playerE = $("#player").get(0);
var isPaused = true;

player.bind("pause", function() {
  isPaused = true;
});

player.bind("play", function() {
  isPaused = false;
});

/** Added for testing **/

function check() {
  alert(isPaused);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="player" src="http://98678871.ngrok.io/music/test.mp3" controls="controls" preload="none"></audio>
<button onclick="check()">Check isPlaying</button>
```

Comment: So there is no way to store this in a variable to reference later on? That would be really useful.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen You can bind events, and change your isPaused variable. I have shown an example in my answer.